# How can I improve loading of javascript files in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, delay, nvd3.js

I have a web application that draws bar charts with NVD3/D3 javascript libraries.

However there seems to be an issue with Chrome because there is always quite some big delay (~8 seconds) before the page is being rendered and I found out with DevTools that the delay is caused by the load of the javascript files. The javascript files are already minified and I made this test with all extensions disabled to rule out other influences.

When I load the same page with IE11 the page is loaded in 2 seconds.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe cache is disabled in DevTools, or you have any throttling settings?

[image]

Comment: cache is not disabled, it also says "(from disk cache)" in DevTools